# Fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04 only displaying on one monitor even though both are detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04

I have a brand new laptop Lenovo Slim Pro 14 x (14ARH7). It has been freshly installed with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. The laptop itself has a mobile GTX 3050 GPU with has the 515 drivers installed and set to performance mode. Two 2560*1440p monitors are connected via display port to a hub then connected via USB C to the laptop. Both refresh rates are set to 59.8HZ. I have used the exact same setup on an older version of Ubuntu with the previous Lenovo Yoga Slim 7 (no discrete graphics) and it worked completely fine.

Both monitors appear in settings but only one will display at a time. I have tried the open source NVIDIA drivers as well as the 510 driver instead of the 515 but they had no effect.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: USB might not be up to actually transferring that amount of data (per second)... [ not checked ]

Comment: But this exact same setup worked on my old laptop which is the same laptop as my current one with a 5800hs instead of a 6800hs and no discrete GPU. So it definitely can support the amount of data at 1440p 60HZ.

Comment: You might wish to study https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB - verify which version of USB you actually have; your laptop, cable AND the HUB needs to be up to it. Estimate with three color channels per pixel, i.e. 3 bytes at least. 3 bytes per pixel, 2(displays)x2560x1440x(three bytes)x60(times per second) = bytes per second.

Comment: It has USB C 3.2 Gen 2 port and USB C 3.2 Gen 2 cables connecting everything. Exact same setup is verified to work on the prior edition of my laptop.

Comment: Well; same driver? - obviously something is different. Settings?

Comment: My previous laptop didn't have discrete graphics, my new one has the NVIDIA 3050m

Comment: Have you tried all three USB-C ports? Looking at the documentation for this model, only two of the three support DisplayPort see [here](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/Yoga/Yoga_Slim_7_Pro_14ARH7/Yoga_Slim_7_Pro_14ARH7_Spec.pdf) Looking again one specifically supports Thunderbolt at 40Gbit/s, this would be port 5 on the image at the top of that document.

Comment: Yes I have tried all the ports, including that one. Could it be an issue with linux thinking it isn't a usb 4 port? How do I check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading my kernel from 5.15 to 5.19 fixed this issue and a couple of other issues I was facing.